# Flickr feed with jQuery and json works in FF but not IE

Tags: jquery, json, flickr

I am having a problem with jQuery and json not appending stuff to a div I have. It works perfectly fine in firefox but not in internet explorer. The website is http://www.mikekorn.ca and the code is being used in the flickr feed at the bottom. Any suggestions?

```
$(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&api_key=956be4b7ea4975744c77e3df0f934143&photoset_id=72157629044896279&extras=url_m&per_page=10&page=1&format=json&nojsoncallback=1", function(data) {
        //alert(data);
        $.each(data.photoset.photo, function(index, item) {
            $("<img/>").attr("src",item.url_m).addClass("opacity").appendTo(".apples").wrap("<div class='test'></div>").wrap("<a href='http://www.flickr.com/photos/32389850@N07/" + item.id + "'></a>");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: The IE version you use supports Cross Domain Request?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to break that line down. You're using a lot of functions which are just completely unnecessary.

Personally, considering I never use jQuery, I would do it in plain JavaScript and have it work first time and unambiguously.